# Find nested array that contains a specific index value node js

Tags: node.js, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach, nested

I am pulling a 2d array from an excel file using Xlsx populate. I want to be able to pass in a /:id that will then pull the nested array that has the index value matching the id from the URL. Here is what I have so far:

```
app.get("/:id", function(req, res){
  var storeID = req.params['id']
  XlsxPopulate.fromFileAsync("./public/dataSheets/customerList.xlsx")
  .then(workbook => {
    
    const allValues = workbook.sheet("All Locations").usedRange().value();
    console.log(allValues);
    


//ending brackets
  });
});
```

Here is what the array looks like. Its a 2D array with index values that I want to match that coming from the URL /:id named storeID

```
 [
    3435,
    'IHOP #3435',
    'Restaurant Manager',
    '4 East Gateway Blvd.',
    'SAVANNAH',
    'GA',
    '31419-7554',
    'Augusta',
    "Children's Hospital of Georgia"
  ],
  [
    3505,
    'IHOP #3505',
    'Restaurant Manager',
    '421 Pooler Parkway, Ste 200',
    'POOLER',
    'GA',
    '31322-5102',
    'Augusta',
    "Children's Hospital of Georgia"
  ],
  [
    3617,
    'IHOP #3617',
    'Restaurant Manager',
    '1248 Knox Ave',
    'North Augusta',
    'SC',
    '29841-4055',
    'Augusta',
    "Children's Hospital of Georgia"
  ],
  [
    3636,
    'IHOP #3636',
    'Restaurant Manager',
    '808 W. Oglethorpe Hwy',
    'Hinesville',
    'GA',
    '31313-4401',
    'Augusta',
    "Children's Hospital of Georgia"
  ],
  ... 1132 more items
```

Please help I am stuck and don't know where to go from here.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I not sure i understand or not but if i correct you can use find method to do this like the code beloww

```
app.get("/:id", function(req, res){

var storeID = req.params['id']
  XlsxPopulate.fromFileAsync("./public/dataSheets/customerList.xlsx")
  .then(work

book => {

const allValues = workbook.sheet("All Locations").usedRange().value();
const store = arrValues.find(item => item[0] == storeID);
console.log(store);

//ending brackets
  });
});
```

It not tested yet but i think it will work